# UIAccessibilityFocus protocol not working with UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, accessibility, voiceover

With UIAccessibilityFocus protocol, supposedly, if you override accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused() and accessibilityElementDidLoseFocus(), you will be able to track when an accessible element gain or lose focus while Voiceover is running.  This seems to work well with all field types - UIButton, UILabel, UISwitch, UITextView, etc. - except UITextField.  When Voiceover focus is on (or leaving) an UITextField, those functions are simply not called.  Just wondering if it is a bug or something else.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature, let me explain.

Without VoiceOver turned on there is no concept of focus within iOS.  Except in the case of UITextField.  UITextFields get "focused" (again focus isn't really a concept in iOS without voiceover) with or without VoiceOver on.  For the other elements, this is not the case.  They do not have "gainFocus" equivalents.  A UIButton gaining focus is only meaningful from an accessibility standpoint.  So they add in the special accessibilityElementDidGainFocus calls for those classes.  They are specifically removed from UITextFields because that call would be logically equivalent to calls that already exist for that class, independent of the Accessibility API.